# A committee of $8$ workers is formed selecting from a group of $6$ men and $5$ women. How many different committees can be formed if the committee…

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I need help with a question. I have absolutely no idea how to do this, can someone please explain how to solve this problem:

> A committee of $8$ workers is formed selecting from a group of $6$ men and $5$ women. How many different committees can be formed if the committee should contain exactly $5$ men?

Comment: Exactly $5$ or $5$ or more?
If is exact What if you choose them separately and use multiplication principle?

Comment: Exactly 5 men .

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  choose the $5$ men out of $6$ and note that you have to choose $3$ women out of $5$

Comment: What formula can I use to solve it??

Answer (score 1):

Well select $5$ of $6$ men and then $3$ out of the $5$ women. So
$$\binom{6}{5}\binom{5}{3}$$

Comment: How do I solve that though

Comment: Well $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ so $\binom{5}{3}=\frac{5!}{3!2!}=\frac{4\times 5}{2\times 1}=10.$ Solve the other one.

Answer (score 0):

We can deal with the two seperately.

For men, we choose 5 out of 6, so

$ {6}\choose{5} $ = $ {6}\choose{6-5} $ = $ {6}\choose{1} $ = $6$

Now for women, we choose 3 out of 5, so

$ {5}\choose{3} $ = $ \frac{5*4*3}{3*2*1} $ = $\frac{60}{6} = 10$

Since the two are independent events, we multiply them together,
$6*10=60$

Comment: It's the same answer as Phicar's.